Trying to change texture dynamically in Gazebo, Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleton().createManual fails silent
I am writing (Gazebo 11.11, ROS2 Galactic) plugin to dynamically change textures of Gazebo objects.
Here is what I have so far (looks scary, but most of this code is error catching and reporting):
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <gazebo/rendering/rendering.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <gazebo_ros/node.hpp>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/image.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <OgreLogManager.h>

namespace gazebo
{
class LandscapeTexturePlugin : public ModelPlugin
{
public:
    LandscapeTexturePlugin() : ModelPlugin() 
    {
        Ogre::LogManager::getSingleton().createLog("/home/username/SnowCron/ros_projects/harsh/srcOgre.log", true, true, true);
    }

    void Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
    {
        // Store the model pointer
        this->model = _model;

        // Initialize ROS node
        this->ros_node = gazebo_ros::Node::Get(_sdf);

        // Create a subscriber for the texture update topic
        this->texture_sub = this->ros_node->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>(
            "update_landscape_texture", 10,
            std::bind(&LandscapeTexturePlugin::OnTextureUpdate, this, std::placeholders::_1));

        // Use a timer instead of connecting to the world update event
        this->update_timer = this->ros_node->create_wall_timer(
            std::chrono::milliseconds(100),
            std::bind(&LandscapeTexturePlugin::OnUpdate, this));

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> LandscapeTexturePlugin loaded successfully");
    }

private:
    void OnUpdate()
    {
        if (!this->visual && rendering::get_scene())
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Trying to find visual...");
            // this->visual = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<rendering::Visual>(
            //     rendering::get_scene()->GetVisual("ground_plane::landscape_link::visual"));
std::string model_name = this->model->GetName();
std::string visual_name = model_name + "::landscape_link::visual";
RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Trying to find visual with name: %s", visual_name.c_str());
this->visual = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<rendering::Visual>(rendering::get_scene()->GetVisual(visual_name));
            if (this->visual)
            {
                this->initial_material_name = this->visual->GetMaterialName();
                RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Visual found. Initial material: %s", this->initial_material_name.c_str());
            }
            else
            {
                RCLCPP_WARN(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> ! Visual not found");
            }
        }
    }
    
    void OnTextureUpdate(const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::SharedPtr msg)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this->visual)
            {
                RCLCPP_WARN(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Visual not found yet. Skipping texture update.");
                return;
            }

Ogre::Root::getSingletonPtr()->addResourceLocation(
    "/usr/share/gazebo-11/media",
    "FileSystem",
    "Gazebo");
Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().initialiseAllResourceGroups();

Ogre::Root* root = Ogre::Root::getSingletonPtr();
if (!root)
{
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Ogre root not found. Ogre might not be properly initialized.");
    return;
}

            // Convert ROS image to OpenCV format
            cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
            cv::Mat image = cv_ptr->image;

            // Create a new Gazebo texture
            common::Image gazebo_image;
            gazebo_image.SetFromData(image.data, image.cols, image.rows, common::Image::RGB_INT8);

            // Create a new material name
            std::string material_name = "LandscapeMaterial_" + std::to_string(this->texture_count++);

            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Material Name: %s", this->visual->GetMaterialName().c_str());

            // Get the material
            // Ogre::MaterialPtr ogre_material = Ogre::MaterialManager::getSingleton().getByName(
            //     this->visual->GetMaterialName(), Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME);

            if (!Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().resourceGroupExists(Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME)) 
            {
                RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Resource group doesn't exist");
                Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().createResourceGroup(Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME);
            }

            Ogre::MaterialPtr ogre_material = Ogre::MaterialManager::getSingleton().create(
                material_name, Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME);

            if(ogre_material.isNull())
            {
                RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Failed to get material, DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME: %s",
                    Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME.c_str());
                return;
            }                


Ogre::Technique* technique = ogre_material->getTechnique(0); // Assuming first technique
RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05b");

Ogre::Pass* pass = technique->getPass(0); // Assuming first pass
RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05c");

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pass->getNumTextureUnitStates(); ++i) {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05d");
    Ogre::TextureUnitState* texUnit = pass->getTextureUnitState(i);
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05e");
    Ogre::String textureName = texUnit->getTextureName();
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05f, %s", texUnit->getTextureName().c_str());
    Ogre::TexturePtr texture = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingletonPtr()->getByName(textureName);
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05g");
}

            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05, %d, %d", image.cols, image.rows);


            // Create and set the texture
            Ogre::TexturePtr texture = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleton().createManual(
                material_name + "_texture",
                Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
                Ogre::TEX_TYPE_2D,
                image.cols, image.rows, 0, Ogre::PF_B8G8R8,
                Ogre::TU_DYNAMIC_WRITE_ONLY_DISCARDABLE);

            //Ogre::TexturePtr texture = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingletonPtr()->getByName(this->initial_material_name);

            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05a");

            // Copy image data to the texture
            Ogre::HardwarePixelBufferSharedPtr pixelBuffer = texture->getBuffer();

            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 06");

            pixelBuffer->blitFromMemory(Ogre::PixelBox(image.cols, image.rows, 1, Ogre::PF_B8G8R8, image.data));

            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 07");

            // Set up material properties
            ogre_material->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->createTextureUnitState(material_name + "_texture");

            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 07");

            ogre_material->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setSceneBlending(Ogre::SBT_TRANSPARENT_ALPHA);

            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 08");

            ogre_material->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setDepthWriteEnabled(false);

            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 09");

            // Apply the new material to the visual
            this->visual->SetMaterial(material_name);

            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 10");
        }
        catch (const Ogre::Exception& e) {
            std::string ogre_error = e.getFullDescription().c_str();
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), "Ogre exception: %s, %s", ogre_error.c_str(), e.what());
        } catch (const std::exception& e) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), "Standard exception: %s", e.what());
        } catch (...) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), "Unknown exception");
        }
    }

    physics::ModelPtr model;
    rendering::VisualPtr visual;
    std::string initial_material_name;
    gazebo_ros::Node::SharedPtr ros_node;
    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::SharedPtr texture_sub;
    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr update_timer;
    int texture_count = 0;
};

GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(LandscapeTexturePlugin)
}

Now, important part is
Ogre::Technique* technique = ogre_material->getTechnique(0); // Assuming first technique
RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05b");

Ogre::Pass* pass = technique->getPass(0); // Assuming first pass
RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05c");

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pass->getNumTextureUnitStates(); ++i) {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05d");
    Ogre::TextureUnitState* texUnit = pass->getTextureUnitState(i);
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05e");
    Ogre::String textureName = texUnit->getTextureName();
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05f, %s", texUnit->getTextureName().c_str());
    Ogre::TexturePtr texture = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingletonPtr()->getByName(textureName);
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05g");
}

            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 05, %d, %d", image.cols, image.rows);


            // Create and set the texture
            Ogre::TexturePtr texture = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleton().createManual(
                material_name + "_texture",
                Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
                Ogre::TEX_TYPE_2D,
                image.cols, image.rows, 0, Ogre::PF_B8G8R8,
                Ogre::TU_DYNAMIC_WRITE_ONLY_DISCARDABLE);

Initially, there only was
    Ogre::TexturePtr texture = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleton().createManual(
        material_name + "_texture",
        Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
        Ogre::TEX_TYPE_2D,
        image.cols, image.rows, 0, Ogre::PF_B8G8R8,
        Ogre::TU_DYNAMIC_WRITE_ONLY_DISCARDABLE);

But it crashes. Or should I say, Gazebo crashes, and I wasn't able to find any reasons or to make it to produce error report.
Then I have added the cycle, the idea was that I'll get name of a texture of the object I work with, and then use
Ogre::TexturePtr texture = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingletonPtr()->getByName(textureName);

instead of calling the code that crushes. But
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pass->getNumTextureUnitStates(); ++i)

returns 0 (we are not entering cycle). In the meantime, the object does have texture, i can see it in Gazebo...
Please help.

Any suggestions?
